# Weak convergence, and Cesaro convergence (of mu_n (E) ) imply convergence (of mu_n (E))?

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $X$ be a compact metric Borel space. Suppose $\mu_{n}(A)\rightarrow\mu(A)$
for all $\mu-$continuity sets $A$ (sets with zero boundary measure), where $\mu_{n}$ is a sequence of probability measures.
(some people call it weak other weak* convergence)

If $E$ is a measurable set such that 
$\mu(E)>0$ and the Cesaro average of $\mu_{n}(E)$ converges; can we conclude
that $\mu_{n}(E)$ converges?

Can we conclude this with extra hypothesis?

I am particularly interested in the case when $T:X\rightarrow X$ is a
continuous transformation, $\mu_{n}=T^{n}\mu_{1},$ and $E=\cap T^{-i}A_{i}$
where $A_{i}$ is a sequence of $\mu-$continuity sets.

Comment: In your assumption do you mean that the Cesaro averages of $\mu_n(E)$ converge to $\mu(E)$?

Comment: And what is here a "μ−continuity set A" ?

Comment: @Pietro I think a $\mu$-continuity set is a set whose boundary has $\mu$ measure $0$ (and I think it should have been stated in the OP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the answer is "no", because $\mu_n(E)$ can be an arbitrary sequence of zeros and ones.
Take on the real line $E$={$0$}, and $\mu_n=\delta_{x_n}$, where $x_n$ tends to $0$.
We have $\mu_n\to\delta_0$ weakly.
Then $\mu_n(E)=1$ or $0$ depending on whether $x_n=0$ or not. So you can choose such sequence $x_n$
that Cesaro means do not converge.

In the dynamical setting, I don't know the answer, but I suppose that in such generality it will
be also "no".

Comment: Thanks, I was not looking for the case when the cesaro means do not converge. I wanted that as a part of the hypothesis. But I think your counter example works, if you take $x_{n}$=0 only sporadically, then you will have cesaro mean convergence but not convergence.  